# Image Upload with preview

Tags: asp.net

preview an image just after browsing and before uploading in IE 7.0 using asp.net and vb.net or java script.i have tried below coding

```
function DoPreview()
{
  var filename = document.form1.filesent.value;
  var Img = new Image();
//    if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
//    {
//      alert("Previews do not work in Netscape.");
//    }
//    else
//{
  Img.src = filename;
  document.images[0].src = Img.src;
// }
}

function CheckUpload()
{
  var filename = document.form1.filesent.value;
  var extension;
  var valid = true
  var Img1 = new Image()
  if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
  {
    alert("This upload function cannot be used with Netscape.");
    valid = true;
  }
  else if (filename == '')
  {
    valid = false;
    alert("Please include a file.");
  }
  else
  {  
    extension = filename.substring(filename.length - 3, filename.length);
    if (extension.toUpperCase() != 'jpg')
    {
      valid = false  ;
      alert("The file must be a jpg.");
    }
    else
    {
      Img1.src = filename;
      if ((Img1.height == 0) || (Img1.width == 0))
      {
        valid = false;
        alert("The file is invalid.");
      }
      else
      {
        document.form1.height.value = Img1.height;
        document.form1.width.value = Img1.width;
      }
    }
  }
  return valid
}

<form method="post"  action ="Default.aspx"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" onsubmit="return CheckUpload()">
    <input type="hidden" name="height" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="width" value="0" />
    <input type="file" name="filesent"  onchange ="DoPreview()" />

    <br/>
 </form>
 <img  id ="imagepreview" src="" name="image1" alt ="Image"  />
```

its working in IIS 5.1 but image preview not displaying in IE 7.0

Comment: Please put your code into a code section.

Comment: I think that you try to preview images that is not on your computer - I am not sure that this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cant get preview for the image which you selected in File Upload control. Actually image can view only through virtual directory of server in browser using URL. The above code shows that you are trying to set preview of an image which is client side (not stored in server) and this is not possible. You can do image preview by storing the image in server side (uploading the image to server).